# Extract data from a WMS with database

Tags: wms, sql, database

In my project, I have a connection to a WMS layer (https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WMS_Cache_PLIS_Geodaten).
The layer seems to be connected to a database. With the "get feature info (i)" tool, I am able to get access to the data behind the WMS layer. The picture shows the WMS layer and on the right side the information I can get with the "get info" tool on the left (e.g. "Rechtsstand: Geplant").

[image]

I am wondering, what kind of database there is behind this WMS layer. I don't quite get this info from the WMS itself...

- Is there a way to get more information about the database (to find out if it is some kind of sql DB?), to be able to see if there is a way to make automated queries?
- Is there a tool that allows me to get the data into an attribute table? Preferred would be a vectorized version of the picture with the information from the database copied into it? I managed to export the WMS as a TIFF and then vectorize it, but the data behind it not.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of a WMS service (or really, any service) is to hide specifics of the underlying database to users, so you only have to deal with a generic WMS interface rather than something database specific. So, no, there is no way, other than asking the owner, to get more information.

As for getting the data into an attribute table, your best bet would be to contact the owner, or try to find a WFS service for the same data. If you really *must* use this WMS, you could try to scrape the data by doing repeated `GetFeatureInfo` requests with `INFO_FORMAT=text/plain` (includes geometry) or `INFO_FORMAT=text/xml`. This would be a major hassle though, and also, it is likely that there is a good reason for the data *not* to readily be available in a vector format.